# Firebase function TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined for Action on google

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using Firebase cloud functions as webhook for my action-on-google dialogflow fulfilment.

My index.js file is as below

```
'use strict';

process.env.DEBUG = 'actions-on-google:*';

var requestcall = require('request');
var date = require('date-and-time');
var promise = require('promise');
var AmazonDateParser = require('amazon-date-parser');
var moment = require('moment-timezone');

var accountnum;
var accessToken;
var timePeriod;
var acctnums =[];


// Create functions to handle requests here
const WELCOME_INTENT = 'input.welcome';  // the action name from the Dialogflow intent
const NUMBER_INTENT = 'account_number';  // the action name from the Dialogflow intent
const NUMBER_ARGUMENT = 'number'; // the action name from the Dialogflow intent

const OUT_CONTEXT = 'output_context';
const ACCOUNT_ARG = 'info';
const ACCOUNT_NUM = 'myAccountNum';
const AccountNums = 'AccountNums';
const CURRENCY_SYMBOL = 'CurrencySymbol';
const TIME_ZONE = 'TimeZone';
const STATS_ARG = 'nextStatsData';



const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const {
  SimpleResponse,
  BasicCard,
  Image,
  Suggestions,
  Button
} = require('actions-on-google');

const app = dialogflow(

{debug: true,clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'});

 app.middleware((conv) => {
    
   });



  


app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
   
  
  console.log('Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(conv.headers));
  console.log('Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(conv.body));
  accessToken =conv.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.user.accessToken;
   console.log('accessToken: ' + accessToken);
 
  if (accessToken !== null) {
      
      
      return  getaccountDetails(conv).then((entity)=>{
      return getMessageFromAccount(entity,conv);
      });
     
       
    
  }
  else{
      
     return conv.close(new SignIn('To get your account details'));
     
      
  }
 
  
  });
exports.stats = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

My package.json file is as below

```
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.12.0",
    "amazon-date-parser": "^0.1.5",
    "date-and-time": "^0.6.3",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^6.5.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.9.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.15.0",
    "promise": "^8.1.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I am getting the following error while testing my actions-on-google

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined
    at standard.then.catch (/workspace/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/framework/express.js:37:32)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Error is not in my index.js. The error is in actions-on-google npm modules library at express.js.

I deleted my node modules and installed again and rebuild the code. still same error coming.

Please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Please post the code that's actually running that causes this error; the `package.json` is only half the puzzle! :)

Comment: Thank you @JamesKing for the response. My actual code in index.js is not causing any error. The error is occurring in node modules library classes, you can see the error is on actions-on-google npm library at express.js class . I have edited the quetsion with express.js class also.

Comment: The reason we're asking for your index.js is because it is uncommon to use express directly in a Cloud Function for Firebase, so we need to see exactly what you *are* doing and how it might be working with both express and Cloud Functions. It is not uncommon that something you may be doing gets exposed as an issue in a different library, or you're trying to use a feature that needs setting up differently under Cloud Functions, so causes an error in express. The more information you can provide - the better our chances are of helping you.

Comment: @Prisoner Thank you for the reply. I had updated my index.js in the question. please look into it and help me in solving the issue.

Comment: What are you doing when the error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Cloud Functions for Firebase - I wouldn't have expected that code to be called at all.

I suspect that including the "express" package in your dependencies is bringing in an outside version of express and this is confusing the actions-on-google library, which has the express types separately defined. The a-o-g library uses this library for those who are using express directly to setup the route, and it shouldn't be necessary if you're using Cloud Functions.

I would suggest removing the package, and making sure it is not in your node modules.

Comment: Hi @Prisoner, My index.js is fulfilment webhook code for dialogflow with a-o-g hosted in firebase. As an example I had shown only one intent i.e welcome intent code as my complete code is very big as per our business logic. I followed the code  guidelines from here :https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/reference/nodejsv2/overview
Please guide me if i am in wrong path. 
From 2 years it was working good until I changed my node version to 10 a week ago.
I removed the extra express module and tried again same error is coming. Guide me in fixing this error.

Comment: What were you doing when the error occurs? Does it happen on every webhook call? Just for some Intents? which Intents?

Comment: The error occurs at every webhook call. I am unable to enter into my action.when i call talk to my action it is giving error. When error occurs in my code i can do something. But error is not in my code and it is in node module so i confused and don`t know what to do.When i checked the firebase function logs i got the error message which i updated in my question.